Identifier com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models.Page cannot be correctly instantiated by the Use API (500)
I am facing an issue where I see below error when I load the page
Caused by: org.apache.sling.models.factory.MissingElementsException: Could not inject all required fields into class com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.models.v2.PageImpl
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:754)
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.internalCreateModel(ModelAdapterFactory.java:428)
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createModel(ModelAdapterFactory.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.JavaUseProvider.loadObject(JavaUseProvider.java:183)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.JavaUseProvider.provide(JavaUseProvider.java:130)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.UseRuntimeExtension.call(UseRuntimeExtension.java:71)
    ... 173 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.sling.models.factory.MissingElementException: Could not inject private com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.models.v2.PageImpl.componentContext
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:738)
        ... 178 more
    Caused by: org.apache.sling.models.factory.ModelClassException: No injector returned a non-null value!
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.injectElement(ModelAdapterFactory.java:615)
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:733)
        ... 178 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.sling.models.factory.MissingElementException: Could not inject protected com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.models.v1.PageImpl.currentPage


